# How does multiple variable assignment work?

Tags: go

Please check the below sample code, and look into 3rd line.

```
a := [3]int{10,20} 
var i int = 50
i, a[2] = 100, i

fmt.Println(i)   //100
fmt.Println(a)   //[10 20 50]
```

I have overwritten the value `100` in `i` variable and immediately applied the int array. When I printed the array, the new value was not printed. How does multiple variable assignment work in Go? Why the `i` value is not updated into the array immediately?

Comment: However this works in Go, please don't write code like this it's very confusing.

Comment: Writing the assignments on a single line doesn't make the assignments any more "immediate". Everything has to be evaluated in the specified order regardless of it being in one or more statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [assigment section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) of the Go spec mentions:

> The assignment proceeds in two phases.
>
> - First, the operands of [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [pointer indirections](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) (including implicit pointer indirections in [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)) on the left and the expressions on the right are [all evaluated in the usual order](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation).
> - Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

That means:

```
var i int = 50
i, a[2] = 100, i
```

- `a[2]` is assigned the `i` evaluated *before* assignment (`50`)
- `i` is assigned `100`

Answer (score 3):

This is intended and described in the [Go language specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments).

Basically it is one statement which happens to assign 2 values to 2 variables. The effects of the statement are available/visible when the statement is fully executed, like with any other expression.

The value of `i` changes the moment you "hit" line 4, so at the time of the assignment to `a[3]` its value is still `50`.